# How to concatenate in cell C all values in column B matching column A using google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have Building Names in column A and Unit Numbers in column B. Would it be possible for me to concatenate in column C all Unit Numbers matching a Building Name? I'm using Google Sheets and have tried the below formula.

`=IF(A2=A1, C1 & ", " & B2, B2)`

Comment: Please share a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows your desired results.